# Issue when adding new rows (with nested dataframes within) to a dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, nested, jsonlite

I am working with complex JSON files in R (by using jsonlite package) and I need to append rows to a dataframa which contains nested dataframes within.

Here is the structure of the original dataframe (**df**, with just a single observation on which I want to add new rows) and also the structure of the new row I wish to add (**new_element**).

```
> str(df)
 $ :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ created_at        : chr "2017-10-20 08:55:13"
  ..$ status            : chr "Done"
  ..$ validation_results:'data.frame':  1 obs. of  4 variables:
  .. ..$ conversions    : chr "OK"
  .. ..$ boxes_shipped  : chr "OK"
  .. ..$ outlook_history: chr "OK"
  .. ..$ write2db       : chr "OK"

> str(new_element)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ created_at        : chr "2017-10-20 09:20:30"
 $ status            : chr "Pending"
 $ validation_results:'data.frame': 1 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ conversions    : chr "NEW"
  ..$ boxes_shipped  : chr "NEW"
  ..$ outlook_history: chr "NEW"
  ..$ write2db       : chr "NEW"
```

**The issue comes here. When trying to add new_element to df:**

```
df <- rbind(df, new_element)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‘1’
```

As for names:

```
> names(df)
[1] "created_at"         "status"             "validation_results"
> names(new_element)
[1] "created_at"         "status"             "validation_results"
```

Does anyone have any hint of what's actually happening?

**EDIT:**

As requested by @Moody_Mudskipper I add the dput outputs.

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(created_at = "2017-10-20 12:15:52", status = "Done", 
validation_results = structure(list(conversions = "OK", 
boxes_shipped = "OK", outlook_history = "OK", write2db = "OK"), .Names = c("conversions", 
"boxes_shipped", "outlook_history", "write2db"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("created_at", "status", 
"validation_results"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")

> dput(new_element)
structure(list(created_at = "2017-10-20 12:16:12", status = "Pending", 
validation_results = structure(list(conversions = "NEW", 
boxes_shipped = "NEW", outlook_history = "NEW", write2db = "NEW"), .Names = c("conversions", 
"boxes_shipped", "outlook_history", "write2db"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("created_at", "status", 
 "validation_results"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")
```

**EDIT2:**

That is the resulting dataframe output I am looking forward to obtain and which will work to convert to a JSON file by using jsonlite package.

```
> str(result)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ created_at        : chr  "2017-10-20 08:55:13" "2017-10-20 09:20:30"
 $ status            : chr  "Done" "Pending"
 $ validation_results:'data.frame': 2 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ conversions    : chr  "OK" "NEW"
  ..$ boxes_shipped  : chr  "OK" "NEW"
  ..$ outlook_history: chr  "OK" "NEW"
  ..$ write2db       : chr  "OK" "NEW"

> dput(result)
structure(list(created_at = c("2017-10-20 08:55:13", "2017-10-20 
09:20:30"), status = c("Done", "Pending"), validation_results = structure(list(
conversions = c("OK", "NEW"), boxes_shipped = c("OK", "NEW"
), outlook_history = c("OK", "NEW"), write2db = 
c("OK", "NEW")), .Names = c("conversions", "boxes_shipped", 
"outlook_history", "write2db"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
1:2)), .Names = c("created_at", 
"status", "validation_results"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
1:2)
```

**EDIT3:**

```
> result <- read_from_JSON('output.json')
> jsonlite::toJSON(result, pretty = TRUE)
[
  {
    "created_at": "2017-10-20 08:55:13",
    "status": "Done",
    "validation_results": {
    "conversions": "OK",
    "boxes_shipped": "OK",
    "outlook_history": "OK",
    "write2db": "OK"
    }
  },
  {
    "created_at": "2017-10-20 09:20:30",
    "status": "Pending",
    "validation_results": {
    "conversions": "NEW",
    "boxes_shipped": "NEW",
    "outlook_history": "NEW",
    "write2db": "NEW"
    }
  }
 ] 
> str(result)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ created_at        : chr  "2017-10-20 08:55:13" "2017-10-20 09:20:30"
 $ status            : chr  "Done" "Pending"
 $ validation_results:'data.frame': 2 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ conversions    : chr  "OK" "NEW"
  ..$ boxes_shipped  : chr  "OK" "NEW"
  ..$ outlook_history: chr  "OK" "NEW"
  ..$ write2db       : chr  "OK" "NEW"
```

Comment: please give `dput(df)` and `dput(new_element)`, we can't do much without data

Comment: I just added the info in the threat. Any inputs will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: that's much better ;). see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After close examination of the difference between `new_element` and `result[2,]` :

```
new_element <- within(new_element,rownames(validation_results) <- 2)
new_df <- rbind(df,new_element)
identical(new_df,result)
# FALSE -> not all mysteries are solved
identical(toJSON(new_df,pretty=TRUE),toJSON(result,pretty=TRUE))
# TRUE -> but that should be good enough
```

**EDIT:**

A general solution, based on @Parfait's answer, that will work to rbind any amount of data.frames that share the same structure, with no prior knowledge on the column classes  :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
rbind2 <- function(...){
  df_cols <- sapply(list(...)[[1]],function(x) "data.frame" %in% class(x))
  df_list <- lapply(list(...),`[`,df_cols) %>% transpose %>% lapply(do.call,what=rbind)
  new_df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(list(...),`[`,!df_cols))     # columns that are not data.frames, simple rbind
  for (n in names(df_list)){
    new_df[[n]] <- df_list[[n]]
  }
  new_df[names(list(...)[[1]])]
}
new_df <- rbind2(df,new_element)
identical(new_df,result) # TRUE
```

you can try this for example:

```
rbind2(result,result)
```

**Old answer:**

The source format is a bit awkward, so we'll do a bit of wrangling to set the `validation_results` column as a list of `data.frames`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
new_df <- list(df,new_element) %>% map(. %>% map_at("validation_results",list)) %>% bind_rows
#              created_at  status   validation_results
#                   <chr>   <chr>               <list>
#   1 2017-10-20 12:15:52    Done <data.frame [1 x 4]>
#   2 2017-10-20 12:16:12 Pending <data.frame [1 x 4]>
```

You might want to use `unnest` at some point

```
library(tidyr)
new_df %>% unnest(validation_results)
# A tibble: 2 x 6
#              created_at  status conversions boxes_shipped outlook_history write2db
#                   <chr>   <chr>       <chr>         <chr>           <chr>    <chr>
#   1 2017-10-20 12:15:52    Done          OK            OK              OK       OK
#   2 2017-10-20 12:16:12 Pending         NEW           NEW             NEW      NEW
```

Comment: That would be indeed a solution. I really appreciate your effort. Thanks! However, when converting the structure to JSON it doesn't work as I would like to. I just added as an EDIT2 the dataframe output structure I am looking for. Would be able to take it a look as well?

Comment: I see... I must admit these nested data.frames are confusing. Have you written the structure of your result by hand ? because it doesn't make much sense to me (to have your 2 observations embedded into 2 observations). Can you share the line you try to convert back to JSON, if this is really the goal we may go there directly

Comment: I did read a 'already appended' JSON file I made and read it using jsonlite. Check out EDIT3. Thanks so much! :)

Comment: Now that you can see the JSON, your solution would output:     "validation_results": [{
    "conversions": "NEW",
    "boxes_shipped": "NEW",
    "outlook_history": "NEW",
    "write2db": "NEW"
    }] -> Notice the [] before {} which made validation_results turn to be a list of objects.

Comment: I updated my solution, tell me if it solves your issue

Comment: The rbind2 function works smoothly. Thanks very very much for taking the time for solving this out. I really appreciate your effort and made me learn new quality things. :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider base R's `data.frame()` constructor binding vectors with column assignment:

```
desired_df <- data.frame(
  create_at = c(df$created_at, new_element$created_at),
  status = c(df$status, new_element$status),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# ASSIGN NESTED DF TO NEW COLUMN
desired_df$validation_results = rbind(df$validation_results, 
                                      new_element$validation_results)

str(desired_df)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ create_at         : chr  "2017-10-20 12:15:52" "2017-10-20 12:16:12"
#  $ status            : chr  "Done" "Pending"
#  $ validation_results:'data.frame':   2 obs. of  4 variables:
#   ..$ conversions    : chr  "OK" "NEW"
#   ..$ boxes_shipped  : chr  "OK" "NEW"
#   ..$ outlook_history: chr  "OK" "NEW"
#   ..$ write2db       : chr  "OK" "NEW"
```

And if needing a flat dataframe (no nested one), do not assign a new column and move `rbind()` call inside `data.frame()`:

```
desired_df <- data.frame(
  create_at = c(df$created_at, new_element$created_at),
  status = c(df$status, new_element$status),
  rbind(df$validation_results, new_element$validation_results),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

str(desired_df)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  6 variables:
#  $ create_at      : chr  "2017-10-20 12:15:52" "2017-10-20 12:16:12"
#  $ status         : chr  "Done" "Pending"
#  $ conversions    : chr  "OK" "NEW"
#  $ boxes_shipped  : chr  "OK" "NEW"
#  $ outlook_history: chr  "OK" "NEW"
#  $ write2db       : chr  "OK" "NEW"
```

Comment: cool :). You can make the first step a bit lighter by typing : `desired_df<- cbind(rbind(df[1:2],new_element[1:2]))` then `desired_df$validation_results = rbind(df[[3]],new_element[[3]])`. We still don't have a real general solution though...